# Tor Browser Disappears After Re-Booting

Tags: tor-browser-bundle

I am a beginner and successfully installed Tor Browser (64-bit) for Kali Linux on my MacBook. The Tor Browser icon was present in the Usual Applications folder on the Kali Linux desktop, but when I shut down and rebooted it was no longer displayed and I could not find Tor via search. Any ideas why this is happening and how to resolve? Thanks.